# Problem with Debugging on physical device on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

Hello i have a Capacitor 3 project. When i run it on my iPhone from Xcode it installs the app just fine. When i try to run from Visual Studio terminal with `npx cap run ios`   i am getting an error

```
✖ Deploying App.app to 0db96bf865b5ea0456255df27edd9260a11384ac - failed!
[error] ERR_UNKNOWN: Path
'/Users/macuse23/Desktop/capacitor/ios/DerivedData/0db96bf865b5ea0456255df27edd9260a11384ac/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app'
        not found
```

Any help? What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I found a way to fix the Problem and 2 Workarounds.
I guess in XCode your app target name is “App”.

**Fix:**

Change the Target name as explained in Capacitorjs documentation
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/configuration#renaming-your-app

“capacitor.config.json” file add iOS scheme.

```
...
"ios": {
    "scheme": "YOUR_APP_NAME"
}
```

Run on Ios emulator

```
ionic cap run ios --livereload --target=TARGET_ID
```

Run on physical device:

```
ionic cap run ios --livereload --external --target= TARGET_ID
```

**Workaround 1:**

Open `node_modules/@capacitor/cli/dist/ios/update.js`

Replace

```
// Replace
const appName = `${config.ios.scheme}.app`;
// With
const appName = `App.app`;
```

Run livereload command

It is not sustainable solution as after each npm install your change will be rollback.

**Workaround 2:**

Run `ionic cap run ios --livereload --target=TARGET_ID`

Go to the error folder `/Users/macuse23/Desktop/capacitor/ios/DerivedData/0db96bf865b5ea0456255df27edd9260a11384ac/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/`

Rename the folder `YOUR_APP_NAME.app` to `APP.app`

Re-run `ionic cap run ios --livereload --target=TARGET_ID`

It is fast to try but I also had checksum issues.

I hope this Helps